# Split retornando IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho um arquivo que as linhas possuem este padrão:

```
0.22755189537     SN.node[0].Application                   SENDING BEACON # 0
0.22755189537     SN.node[0].Application                   Sending [Beacon] of size 105 bytes to communication layer
0.22755189537     SN.node[0].Communication.Radio           Buffered [BypassRouting packet] from MAC layer
0.22755189537     SN.node[0].Communication.Radio           SET STATE to TX, delay=1e-05, power=62
0.227561895369    SN.node[1].Communication.Radio           START signal from node 0 , received power -87.6124dBm
0.231689895368    SN.node[0].Communication.Radio           TX finished (no more pkts in the buffer) changing to RX
0.231689895368    SN.node[1].Communication.Radio           END signal from node 0
0.231689895368    SN.node[1].Communication.Radio           Received packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from node 0, with no interference
0.231699895368    SN.node[1].Application                   RECEBIDO BEACON #0 - ORIGEM 0 - SALTOS 0
```

tentei fazer um split para pegar o valor entre [ ], desta forma: x.split()[1].split('[')[1][0] porém dá erro IndexError: list index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que você quer separar apenas o valor entre os colchetes.

Ler cada linha do `arquivo.txt` e fatiando na coluna desejada.

Depois resta apenas adicionar a fatia extraída da linha em uma lista.

```
lista=[] 

arq = open("arquivo.txt", "r")

for linha in arq :

        lista.append(linha[26:27])

arq.close()
```

Para imprimir a lista:

```
for l in lista:

        print(l)
```

Saída:

```
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
1
```

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, porém eu estava tentando o split, pois necessito de outras informações da linha também. Para esclarecer: eu pego o valor de um nó (0 ou 1) e depois na terceira parte eu tenho uma ocorrência. Quero verificar quantas ocorrências surgiram do tipo RECEBIDO para cada nó (somente um contador) e quantas ocorrências SENDING ocorreram também para cada nó.

Comment: Como ficaria a saída do que você precisa?

Comment: Neste primeiro momento é bem simples, algo como: Nó[0] - x ENVIADOS

Comment: Nó[1] - x RECEBIDOS

Comment: Na verdade são ao todo 36 nós (0 a 35) e eu teria que ler o arquivo, e verificar cada um dos nós quantos RECEBIDOS e quantos SENDING ocorreram.

Comment: Só que não sei nem por onde começar com 36 nós, com dois eu pensei em if/else (se for 1...senão 0, kkk)

Comment: com 36 eu pensei em criar um case com 36 entradas, cada linha corresponde a um nó, logo a linha correspondente no no case teria um if RECEBIDO (recebidoX ++) elif SENDING (sendingx ++) else nada. Mas não sei se minha lógica está certa.

Comment: por fim a saída poderia ser igual a uma tabela

Comment: Nó   |   ENVIADOS    |    RECEBIDOS

Comment: 1   |      xxxx      |        xxxx

Comment: Não sei se tu entendeu como funciona para fatiar a linha... Por exemplo: `linha[26:27]` retorna somente `0` ou `1` porque começa a fatiar na coluna 26 e termina na 27. Se fosse `linha[25:28]` a saída seria `[0]` ou `[1]` e assim por diante. Modifique no exemplo da minha resposta para você entender melhor. Experimente a lógica que você imaginou  e se não funcionar faça uma nova pergunta. Boa sorte!

Comment: Éder, depois que segui esta lógica e a ideia que você me deu, percebi que não funcionou

Comment: repare que são mais de 100.000 linhas entra o append só funciona na primeira parte

Comment: Posta o teu código e a mensagem de erro (se tiver).

Comment: Éder, já alterei um monte de coisas e consegui melhorar um pouco, usando o split. Porém ainda falta muito para dar certo. Se quiser dar uma olhada https://repl.it/repls/GrizzledVillainousDebuggers

Comment: Olhei o código. A lógica está errada. Preciso entender o que você quer fazer. Então vamos ver se eu te entendo: Se `SENDING` ou `Sending` for igual a `1` então `contador_send` é incrementado. Depois, se `Received` ou `RECEBIDO` for igual a `1` então `contador_recebido` é incrementado. É isto que você precisa?

Comment: Olá Éder, não seria isso. Consegui fazer depois de apanhar um pouco. Repare, eu tenho dois nós que enviam x pacotes entre eles. Preciso contabilizar quantos pacotes cada nó enviou e quantos cada nó recebeu. Então eu fiz um if para verificar se o nó é 0, caso não, só pode ser 1. Dentro do if/else eu fiz um segundo if verificando RECEBIDO, senão SENDING. Foi essa lógica que segui.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Com paciência e persistência da para superar muita coisa. Fico feliz que tenha tido sucesso na tua empreitada. Parabéns!